# Weak reference to Python class method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Python 2.7 docs for weakref module say this:

> Not all objects can be weakly referenced; those objects which can
>   include class instances, functions written in Python (but not in C),
>   methods (both bound and unbound), ...

And Python 3.3 docs for weakref module say this:

> Not all objects can be weakly referenced; those objects which can
>   include class instances, functions written in Python (but not in C),
>   instance methods, ...

To me, these indicate that weakrefs to bound methods (in all versions Python 2.7 - 3.3) should be good, and that weakrefs to unbound methods should be good in Python 2.7.

Yet in Python 2.7, creating a weakref to a method (bound or unbound) results in a dead weakref:

```
>>> def isDead(wr): print 'dead!'
...
>>> class Foo: 
...    def bar(self): pass
...
>>> wr=weakref.ref(Foo.bar, isDead)
dead!
>>> wr() is None
True
>>> foo=Foo()
>>> wr=weakref.ref(foo.bar, isDead)
dead!
>>> wr() is None
True
```

Not what I would have expected based on the docs.

Similarly, in Python 3.3, a weakref to a bound method dies on creation:

```
>>> wr=weakref.ref(Foo.bar, isDead)
>>> wr() is None
False
>>> foo=Foo()
>>> wr=weakref.ref(foo.bar, isDead)
dead!
>>> wr() is None
True
```

Again not what I would have expected based on the docs.

Since this wording has been around since 2.7, it's surely not an oversight. Can anyone explain how the statements and the observed behavior are in fact *not* in contradiction?

Edit/Clarification: In other words, the statement for 3.3 says "instance methods can be weak referenced"; doesn't this mean that it is reasonable to expect that weakref.ref(an instance method)() is not None? and if it None, then "instance methods" should not be listed among the types of objects that can be weak referenced?

Comment: @Bakuriu -- You're comment about py3k is correct, but I think you're mis-reading the documentation about bound and unbound methods being not referable.

Comment: @Bakuriu the statement for py3k is equivalent to "those objects which can [be weakly referenced] include ... instance methods": this definitely says they are weak referable.

Comment: you _can_ weakref instance methods.  your problem is that the instance method you're getting has no other references, so it's freed as soon as `weakref.ref` returns.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Foo.bar` produces a new unbound method object every time you access it, due to some gory details about descriptors and how methods happen to be implemented in Python.

The class doesn't own unbound methods; it owns functions.  (Check out `Foo.__dict__['bar']`.)  Those functions just happen to have a `__get__` which returns an unbound-method object.  Since nothing else holds a reference, it vanishes as soon as you're done creating the weakref.  (In Python 3, the rather unnecessary extra layer goes away, and an "unbound method" is just the underlying function.)

Bound methods work pretty much the same way: the function's `__get__` returns a bound-method object, which is really just `partial(function, self)`.  You get a new one every time, so you see the same phenomenon.

You can store a method object and keep a reference to *that*, of course:

```
>>> def is_dead(wr): print "blech"
... 
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def bar(self): pass
... 
>>> method = Foo.bar
>>> wr = weakref.ref(method, is_dead)
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> method = None
blech
```

This all seems of dubious use, though  :)

Note that if Python *didn't* spit out a new method instance on every attribute access, that'd mean that classes refer to their methods and methods refer to their classes.  Having such cycles for every single method on every single instance in the entire program would make garbage collection *way* more expensive—and before 2.1, Python didn't even have cycle collection, so they would've stuck around forever.

Comment: instance methods work the same way in 2 and 3; the docs for 3 just removed the mention of unbound methods because those no longer exist

Comment: I take back my original comment that this answer doesn't show how doc statement "instance methods can be weak referenced" and observed behavior "weak.ref(Foo.bar)() is None == true" are consistent. It does in fact show it, but there is a subtlety (to me, anyways) that clouds the issue. So I mark Eevee's as the correct answer, but I make a clarification to his answer in a separate "answer" (doesn't fit in a comment).

Answer (score 6):

@Eevee's answer is correct but there is a subtlety that is important.

The Python docs state that instance methods (py3k) and un/bound methods (py2.4+) can be weak referenced. You'd expect (naively, as I did) that `weakref.ref(foo.bar)()` would therefore be non-None, yet it is None, making the weak ref "dead on arrival" (DOA). This lead to my question, if the weakref to an instance method is DOA, why do the docs say you can weak ref a method?

So as @Eevee showed, you *can* create a *non*-dead weak reference to an instance method, by creating a strong reference to the method object which you give to weakref:

```
m = foo.bar # creates a *new* instance method "Foo.bar" and strong refs it
wr = weakref.ref(m)
assert wr() is not None # success
```

The subtlety (to me, anyways) is that a *new* instance method object is created *every* time you use Foo.bar, so even after the above code is run, the following will fail:

```
wr = weakref.ref(foo.bar)
assert wr() is not None # fails
```

because foo.bar is *new* instance of the "Foo instance" foo's "bar" method, different from m, and there is no strong ref to this new instance, so it is immediately gc'd, even if you have created a strong reference to it earlier (it is not the same strong ref). To be clear,

```
>>> d1 = foo.bla # assume bla is a data member
>>> d2 = foo.bla # assume bla is a data member
>>> d1 is d2
True # which is what you expect
>>> m1 = foo.bar # assume bar is an instance method
>>> m2 = foo.bar
>>> m1 is m2
False  # !!! counter-intuitive
```

This takes many people by surprise since no one expects access to an instance member to be creating a new instance of anything. For example, if foo.bla is a data member of foo, then using foo.bla in your code does not create a new instance of the object referenced by foo.bla. Now if bla is a "function", foo.bla does create a new instance of type "instance method" representing the bound function.

Why the weakref docs (since python 2.4!) don't point that out is very strange, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Note that if you did `wr = weakref.WeakMethod(foo.bar)` then above quirk is taken care of.

Answer (score 3):

While I see that there's an accepted answer as to *why* this should be so, from a simple use-case situation wherein one would like an object that acts as a weakref to a bound method, I believe that one might be able to sneak by with an object as such. It's kind of a runt compared to some of the 'codier' things out there, but it works.

```
from weakref import proxy

class WeakMethod(object):
    """A callable object. Takes one argument to init: 'object.method'.
    Once created, call this object -- MyWeakMethod() -- 
    and pass args/kwargs as you normally would.
    """
    def __init__(self, object_dot_method):
        self.target = proxy(object_dot_method.__self__)
        self.method = proxy(object_dot_method.__func__)
        ###Older versions of Python can use 'im_self' and 'im_func' in place of '__self__' and '__func__' respectively

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Call the method with args and kwargs as needed."""
        return self.method(self.target, *args, **kwargs)
```

As an example of its ease of use:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def foo(self):
        return "My name is {}".format(self.name)

>>> Stick = A("Stick")
>>> WeakFoo = WeakMethod(Stick.foo)
>>> WeakFoo()
'My name is Stick'
>>> Stick.name = "Dave"
>>> WeakFoo()
'My name is Dave'
```

Note that evil trickery will cause this to blow up, so depending on how you'd prefer it to work this may not be the best solution.

```
>>> A.foo = lambda self: "My eyes, aww my eyes! {}".format(self.name)
>>> Stick.foo()
'My eyes, aww my eyes! Dave'
>>> WeakFoo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in __call__
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
>>>
```

If you were going to be replacing methods on-the-fly you might need to use a `getattr(weakref.proxy(object), 'name_of_attribute_as_string')` approach instead. `getattr` is a fairly fast look-up so that isn't the literal worst thing in the world, but depending on what you're doing, YMMV.

Comment: **Note:** Python >= 3.4 now provides a [standard `weakref.WeakMethod` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakMethod) roughly analogous to that implemented above.